# Is this drive still recoverable?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, laptop, toshiba-hard-drive

May I ask expert on hdds here if this status of hard drive via CrystalDisk is still recoverable?

I have this HDD Toshiba MK3252gsx from an old laptop. Plug it in via a HDD reader and it just doesn't load and hangs. In task manager, says 100% of the disk is already used. Also, when I plug it in, my PC hangs when it tries to load it (even Crystal Disk hangs, this record pops up right after I turned it off). I also notice that Internet connection is disconnected. Internet get back on when I turn off the disk.

[image: Toshiba MK3252gsx]

Comment: The Health Status says "caution", but almost every value is exactly 100, which is suspect.  Try plugging it in directly to a SATA connection and retesting, or try a different program to read the SMART values.

Comment: It is not possible to tell based on the info provided, and SMART values dont tell you much about how recoverable data is anyway. The acid test is to try clone /image the disk and see what happens. I use (gnu) ddrescue, but that does require Unix skills I believe.

Comment: "Plug it in via a HDD reader" What kind of 'reader'? USB cannot carry SMART data, so where do you have it connected?

Comment: Most likely the connecting cable or enclosure is not adapted for this old disk.

Comment: Hi all, it is plugged in via a UGREEN USB3.0 to IDE/SATA reader, via USB. I will try to connect it directly via a SATA on the board. The data is not needed. I just need to revive it to be usable. I will update you guys once I tried it. Thank you for your replies!

Comment: Plugging it directly via SATA does the job! I manage to reformat the drive via the windows installation setup in bootable USB. Thank you so much for your help guys!